# How to configer secondar router in micro frontend application in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, micro-frontend

I am working with micro frontend application I have two application one is shell and other is lead
I am using secondary routing in lead application as following
{
path: '',
children: [
{
path: '',
component: LeadShellComponent,
children: [
{
path: 'list',
component: LeadListComponent,
},
{
path: 'board',
component: LeadBoardComponent,
},
{
path: 'create',
component: LeadCreateComponent,
outlet: 'create',
},
{
path: ':Id',
component: LeadDetailComponent,
outlet: 'detail',
},
],
},
],

But my secondary router outlet is giving error in shell

core.js:6479 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '2'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '2'

I am trying to access this from shell as routerLink="lead"

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am also getting same error.

Comment: No I didn't find any Pls let me know if you if it out

Answer (score 0):

Expose all your componets from remote as

```
// For remotes (please adjust)
        name: "remoteapp",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
            './remoteAppModule': './/src/app/remote/remoteapp.module.ts',
            comp1Component: './/src/app/remote/comp1.component.ts',
            comp2Component: './/src/app/remote/comp2.component.ts',
            comp3Component: './/src/app/remote/comp3.component.ts',
        }
```

And in your shell app create a placeholder component and lazy load your remote app's comp1/comp2/comp3 as

In Shell Route :

```
{
    path: 'comp1',
    component : PlaceholderComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'comp2',
    component : PlaceholderComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'comp3',
    component : PlaceholderComponent
  },
```

PlaceHolderComponets looks like as :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-placeholder',
  template: `<div>
  <header #header></header>
  </div>`,
})
export class PlaceholderComponent {
    @ViewChild('header', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true })
  headerContainer!: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private injector: Injector,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private router: Router) {}
  
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      let compIndex = "";
      if(this.router.url === "/comp1") {
        compIndex = "comp1Componet";
      } else if(this.router.url === "/comp2") {
        compIndex = "comp2Component";
      }else if(this.router.url === "/comp3") {
        compIndex = "comp3Component";
      }
    loadRemoteModule(
        {
            type:'module',
            remoteEntry : 'http://localhost:1003/remoteEntry.js',
            exposedModule : compIndex
        }
    )
        .then(module => {
          const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(module[compIndex]);
          this.headerContainer?.createComponent(factory, undefined, this.injector);
        });
  }

}
```

Hope it will Works!